# Roundcube does not add IP address information into sent emails

Tags: security, email, roundcube

Usually the mail client is supposed to add IP information into emails, in order for the sender to be tracked. But when you send emails from Roundcube Webmail/0.8.4+, the IP address of the server is the only one present in the email, which makes it impossible to track the sender or his/her location. Isn't this a flaw in the system? Is this by design or is it a bug? What can be done to solve this, ie. to enable adding IP addresses in emails sent via Roundcube webmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure this in `main.inc.php`:

> // add a received header to outgoing mails containing the creators IP
>   and hostname  $rcmail_config['http_received_header'] = true;

Comment: Take a look at this before you change the default settings: https://blog.ageispolis.net/email-headers/

Comment: Great, but who cares? Better keep important info in emails to help tracking. Who needs to hide their identities anyway?

Comment: Your server, your call :)